# How to interpretate this Kotlin to java decompile mech

Tags: android, kotlin, decompiling

I decompile an Android apk (Kotlin code)trying to understand the code and came across this:

```
public final class RetrofitJSONArrayConverter extends Factory {
    public static final Companion Companion = new Companion();
    private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    @Metadata(bv = {1, 0, 3}, d1 = {"\u0000\u0012\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\b\u0003\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0007\b\u0002¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0002R\u0010\u0010\u0003\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0004X\u0004¢\u0006\u0002\n\u0000¨\u0006\u0005"}, d2 = {"Lio/voiapp/voi/util/RetrofitJSONArrayConverter$Companion;", "", "()V", "MEDIA_TYPE", "Lokhttp3/MediaType;", "app_release"}, k = 1, mv = {1, 1, 13})
    /* compiled from: RetrofitJSONArrayConverter.kt */
    public static final class Companion {
        private Companion() {
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(@NotNull Type type, @NotNull Annotation[] annotationArr, @NotNull Retrofit retrofit) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(type, "type");
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(annotationArr, "annotations");
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(retrofit, "retrofit");
        return Intrinsics.areEqual((Object) JSONArray.class, (Object) type) != null ? (Converter) RetrofitJSONArrayConverter$responseBodyConverter$1.INSTANCE : null;
    }

    @Nullable
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(@NotNull Type type, @NotNull Annotation[] annotationArr, @NotNull Annotation[] annotationArr2, @NotNull Retrofit retrofit) {
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(type, "type");
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(annotationArr, "parameterAnnotations");
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(annotationArr2, "methodAnnotations");
        Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(retrofit, "retrofit");
        return Intrinsics.areEqual((Object) JSONArray.class, (Object) type) != null ? (Converter) RetrofitJSONArrayConverter$requestBodyConverter$1.INSTANCE : null;
    }
}
```

I know that Kotlin code can be badly misinterpreted by the java decompiler 
but how can the decompiler  miss all this method arguments

Any thought on this?

Comment: Why, what's wrong with it?

Comment: The requestBodyConverter and responseBodyConverter has many arguments that never gets used

Comment: And... why is that a problem? Surely they *could* be used, but *aren't* in *this particular case*.

Comment: So you mean like that that programmers for this app has created a method that leads to nowhere like the `requestBodyConverter`

Comment: This is a `Converter.Factory` for Retrofit. `requestBodyConverter` and `responseBodyConverter` are used by Retrofit, the method signatures also come from Retrofit. Clearly, if you want to understand what these method arguments are for, you should read the documentation for Retrofit, specifically https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Converter.Factory.html#requestBodyConverter-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-retrofit2.Retrofit-

Comment: Thanks I understand now